# Is $\mathbb{R}$ complete under the metric $d(x,y) = \lvert x^3 - y^3 \rvert$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Looking at the graph of $y = x^3$ I feel like the answer is yes, but I can't figure out how to prove it. I've tried proving the contrapositive, that if a sequence doesn't converge it's not cauchy, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x_n)$ be Cauchy in $(\mathbb{R},d).$ Then, $(x_n^3)$ is Cauchy in $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|),$ so it converges to some $x'$ (as this space is complete). Let $x=(x')^{1/3}.$ Then, $$d(x_n,x)=|x_n^3-x'|\rightarrow 0.$$ So, yes, it's complete.

Comment: How does one prove if a sequence is cauchy in the difference of cubes metric it is cauchy in the standard metric?

Comment: What I actually claimed is that if $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in the cube metric, then $(x_n^3)$ is Cauchy in the standard metric. This is hopefully clear, since $d(x_n,x_m)=|x_n^3-x_m^3|.$

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your metric function $\ d\ $ is indeed a metric in $\ \mathbb R.\ $ Your metric space $\ \mathbf R' := (\mathbb R\ d)\ $ is
isometric to the standard 1-dim Euclidean space
$\ \mathbf R\ :=\ (\mathbb R\ \rho)\ $ where
$\ \rho(x\ y):=|x-y|\ $ for every $\ x\ y\in\mathbb R $.

It follows that your space $\ \mathbf R'\ $ is complete.